# Computation of an integral on the sphere of dimension 5

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $z_1=x_1+ix_2$, $z_2=x_3+ix_4$ and $z_3=x_5+ix_6$. I would like to compute $$\int_{S^5}\left\vert z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2\right\vert^{2m}d\mu$$where $\mu$ is the usualmeasure invariant by rotations.

According to Mathematica, on small values of $m$, the result should be $\frac{1}{m+1}$ but I do not know how to prove this.

Lef $f(z)$ be the integrand, since it is homogeneous of degree $4m$, I tried to write $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^6} e^{-\Vert z\Vert^2}f(z)dz = \left(\int_0^\infty r^{5+4m}e^{-r^2}dr\right)\left(\int_{S^5}f(z)d\mu\right)$$on the right I get an integral that I know how to compute, and what I am interested in. However I do not know better how to compute the one on the left.